# Adding .xml extension to WCF service

Tags: xml, vb.net, wcf, xml-parsing, windows-mobile-6.5

I have a wcf service that contains xml data with the url http://msi-ecs.com.ph:8090/uom/UOMws.svc/xml/codes
Unfortunately, I need it for windows mobile and it only knows what to do with files by their mime type. This Mime type is mostly de-referenced using the the extension of the file. As the file "codes" does not have an extension, the IE mobile browser does not know what to do with the file and brings an error message.

I've searched far and wide but lady luck doesn't seem to be on my side.

Now, here's the question: How can I add a .xml extension to the url of my wcf service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This - `http://msi-ecs.com.ph:8090/uom/UOMws.svc/xml/codes` is **not** an XML file.  What you're seeing in the browser is the response from the RESTful service at the address you're using.  The service is returning the data in XML.

You can retrieve this quite easily by using `HttpClient` to call the service and then getting the content of the response, like this (very trivial example to give you the general idea):

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("http://msi-ecs.com.ph:8090/uom/UOMws.svc/xml/codes").Result;
string xml = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

This code returns the following as a string (which you can then load into an XDocument for parsing):

```
<ArrayOfCodes xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Codes>
    <active>1</active>
    <id>14</id>
    <quantity>50</quantity>
    <unit>pc</unit>
    <unitid>1</unitid>
    <uom>Piece</uom>
    <value>CPQ247050-001~000</value>
  </Codes>
  <Codes>
    <active>0</active>
    <id>16</id>
    <quantity>30</quantity>
    <unit>bx</unit>
    <unitid>2</unitid>
    <uom>Box</uom>
    <value>CPQ293703-B21~000</value>
  </Codes>
  <Codes>
    <active>1</active>
    <id>17</id>
    <quantity>1</quantity>
    <unit>bx</unit>
    <unitid>2</unitid>
    <uom>Box</uom>
    <value>aaa</value>
  </Codes>
  <Codes>
    <active>1</active>
    <id>15</id>
    <quantity>100</quantity>
    <unit>pk</unit>
    <unitid>3</unitid>
    <uom>Pack</uom>
    <value>CPQ247050-001~0M0</value>
  </Codes>
  <Codes>
    <active>1</active>
    <id>18</id>
    <quantity>2</quantity>
    <unit>hf</unit>
    <unitid>5</unitid>
    <uom>Handfull</uom>
    <value>aaa</value>
  </Codes>
</ArrayOfCodes>
```

**EDIT**

For Windows Mobile, try the following code (note that I ran this on VS 2012 with .NET 4.5, as I don't have the Mobile SDK on my machine, but it worked):

```
string xml = "";

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://msi-ecs.com.ph:8090/uom/UOMws.svc/xml/codes");

using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            xml = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Above code is based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/974310/745969).

**EDIT:  VB.NET **

```
Dim xml As String = ""

Dim request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://msi-ecs.com.ph:8090/uom/UOMws.svc/xml/codes")

Using response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    Using (responseStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
        Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
            xml = reader.ReadToEnd();
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: i don't think that that is applicable to windows mobile.

Comment: Oops - missed that tag. Another example is coming up in a couple minutes.

Comment: Sounds promising but I can't check it yet coz i'm having problems with 'using (dim a b = c)' with all those 3 codes with using. haha.

Comment: Sorry about that - I'm having a bad night reading tags, apparently.  I've added a VB.NET snippet (I haven't tested it yet, but it should get you closer).

Comment: I already got it. although, now i'm having 'unable to read data from the transport connection.'

Comment: Sounds like the server is closing out the underlying socket on large data. How large are these objects? and is the server code designed to handle more than 40 objects? Potentially the server application is going out of bounds or there is some limit for size on the server configuration that prevents large packets coming off the network.http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b0f90f2c-cb07-455d-a740-f34bb66a3912/unable-to-read-data-from-the-transport-connection?forum=netfxcompact

Comment: yeah, it lead to another problem. i'm really an android dev, no idea how i got this project. (-__-') anyway, thank you so much, your answer actually proved some things from my previous code. though still not fully working, thank you.

Comment: @LeiLeyba - Glad I was able to help some.  I understand the challenges of working outside your normal technology - I'm a .NET guy, but 4 years ago I spent most of the year supporting a legacy system written in DOS, Clipper and dBase - and I knew nothing about Clipper or dBase.  It was an interesting year, to say the least.  Good luck with the remainder of your project :)